# How can use the SP.UI.ModalDialog.ShowPopupDialog() function to get a pop up of an img (Sharepoint)?

Tags: html, css, sharepoint

```
</script><a title="Open Dialog" href="javascript:ShowWelcomeDialog();">Open Dialo​g</a> ​<br/>​<br/>​<br/>​<br/>​<br/><a onclick="javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.ShowPopupDialog(&#39;http://pic.jpg&#39;)">Show more!</a> ​<br/>
```

Above is the code sample of what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the code below to achieve it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openDialogWithIamge(){
    var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
    var myhtml = document.createElement('div');
    myhtml.innerHTML="<img src='https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow_wide.jpg'/>";
    options.title= "Show Image",
    options.html = myhtml,  
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="openDialogWithIamge()">Show more!</a> ​<br/>
```

[image]

Comment: this works .. thank you so much . do i use the same code when the img is local in my pc?